# Raspberry Pi on Ubuntu 19.10 - screen resolution not detected [only one resolution offered]

Tags: display, 19.10, raspberrypi

I've installed Ubuntu 19.10 from the default image for Raspberry Pi 4B. I've tried two screens, but the screen resolution(s) are not detected. Only one resolution is offered. For example, on the smaller screen, which is 1280x800, the only resolution offered is 640x480.

However, on my laptop (also on Ubuntu 19.10) both screens work fine (offering a range of resolutions are you would expect).

What do I need to do on the Raspberry Pi to get this sorted out?

Comment: I was able to get the resolution set changing the /boot/firmware/usrconfig.txt file.. I was able to add this to get the resolution set to 1280x1024 hdmi_drive=2
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=35
hdmi_force_hotplug=1 you can check this site out for the options for the file... just make sure you edit the usrconfig.txt not the config.txt file... https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md hope this helps.